# How to change shape of line chart plots in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

```
 plot(rang1,CPUAndroid,'--  gs','Linewidth',1,'MarkerEdgeColor','b','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',5);
 hold on
 plot(rang1,CPUC,'--rs','Linewidth',1,'MarkerEdgeColor','b','MarkerFaceColor','b','MarkerSize',5);         legend('ECC in Local Application Processing','ECC in Remote Server')
```

I want to change the shape of second plot to shape triangle in matlab.Kindly help me in this regard.Thanx

Comment: Have you read http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html or http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html. Perhaps you want `plot(x, y, '-d')`.

Comment: Hint: assign a handle to your plot, then you can change any property you want. Look at the link provided by @Jørgen

Comment: In your call to `plot`, add the following property/value pair  : `'Marker','^'`. And look at [MATLAB Line Specification](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) we are interested in the [`LineSpec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#inputarg_LineSpec) property, specifically the `^` character.

For example:

```
x1 = 1:10;
x2 = (11:20)+3;

figure;
hold on;
plot(x1, '-ob')
plot(x2, '-^r');
```

Gives us:

[image: yay]